# Locus of Hodge classes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, motives, hodge-theory, algebraic-cycles

Let $\pi: X\to S$ be a proper smooth morphism of complex analytic spaces, with connected smooth $X$ and $S$ over $\mathbf{C}$, projective fibers, and $$\mathscr{H}_{X/S}^p := R^p\pi_*\Omega^{\bullet}_{X/S}.$$

Suppose $\pi$ is algebraic and defined over $\mathbf{Q}$.

By Deligne-Cattani-Kaplan, the locus of Hodge classes $\mathscr{H}\text{dg}^{p,p}_{X/S}$ in $\mathscr{H}_{X/S}^p$ is a countable union of closed algebraic subsets.

Is it known that $\mathscr{H}\text{dg}^{p,p}_{X/S}$ is defined over $\overline{\mathbf{Q}}$?

Or, assuming this, is it known that the action of $\text{Gal}(\overline{\mathbf{Q}}/\mathbf{Q})$ on $\mathscr{H}\text{dg}^{p,p}_{X/S}$ sends connected components in $\mathscr{H}\text{dg}^{p,p}_{X/S}$ into $\mathscr{H}\text{dg}^{p,p}_{X/S}$?

In other words, is there any progress on either of these questions?

It is known that if both properties were true, then every Hodge cycle of a fiber (hence every fiber) of $\pi$ is an absolute Hodge cycle in the sense of Deligne.